# Authserver "could not connect" "Host xxxxx not authorized" after changing IP for LAN installation

Tags: mysql, lan, azerothcore

Using default Windows install instructions on a bare Windows 10 installation. I got the server running. Re-stating: this is thus far using ONLY default values; no changes. I was able to log in from another computer using an existing 3.3.5 client, but not enter the realm. I could SEE it, but if I clicked on the realm it would act like it was connecting and then just pop up the realm list again. Repeat endlessly.

Then I remembered I probably needed to change the IP number of the server in the database and/or conf files. I changed the login server ip in `authserver.conf`, and the login,world,and character database ip in `worldserver.conf`; all settings using `192.168.1.112`. In the realm list table, using Heidi, I changed both ip settings to the same LAN ip that the server computer used, `192.168.1.112`. Then I updated the data tab with the same ip, and posted the change. I disconnected and exited Heidi.

Now when I try to start authserver, I get the error in the title:

> Authserver.exe could not connect to mysql, host "nameofservercomputer" is not authorized to connect.

I found this issue brought up in a docker installation question, but it was caused by the live data table not being updated in Heidi. I have done that and still get the same error. I have found other leads that indicate I need to edit the MySQL configuration to allow other connections beyond localhost, but so far they all provide solutions that either assume greater knowledge than I have, or are for using specific tools that I do not have installed and are not familiar with.

Can anyone point to some guidance on this issue? The goal is to set up 1 wow server on a LAN, that all other computers on the lan have access to. I did this once before with a trinitycore server, but that was years ago and I do not remember what I had to do at all.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your auth database, change the realmlist ip from your realm to real ip of the realm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem after scouring the internet and careful reading.

FIRST NOTE: THIS CONFIGURATION IS SPECIFICALLY FOR LAN USE. If it's part of the solution for internet access or anything else, I don't know.

The authserver.conf and worldserver.conf files on the WoW server running Azerothcore need to be left configured for the default localhost address of 127.0.0.1, in the places the setup SEEMS to recommend changing the address to the server's LAN IP. I think that may need to be done ONLY for Internet access. Which I'm not working on. The ONLY place ON THE SERVER CONFIG you need to change the IP number to the LAN number instead of 127.0.0.1 is in the reallist table in the auth database, using whatever mysql editing method you have installed and chosen to use. I'm using Heidi. the LOCAL address will remain 127.0.0.1; change ONLY the "address" field to your LAN IP for your WoW server.

And then, of course, on all lan computers, you will need to change each computer's realmlist file to point to the lan computer's ip. That realmlist file is in the enGB folder that is in the DATA folder that is in the client folder...in my case that would be World of Warcraft 3.3.5a/DATA/enGB/

I hope this helps someone in the future. It applies to TrinityCore, AzerothCore, and I'm sure other builds, too.

Oh, and to explain the error I experienced above, that was because I had changed the ip numbers in the authserver and worldserver conf files, so basically the server was trying to make an EXTERNAL connection to the database instead of an internal, which by default is opposed by security settings.